# Is there any extension example on implementing property editor in vscode?

Tags: vscode-extensions

[image: property editor]

I have been searching thru the documents and tutorials looking for api / extension examples to implement a GUI like the screenshoot above.

Is there any existing api to implement property editor? or do i need to implement GUI from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's not. You can implement an own GUI via webviews, but that's about it.